Kafka Cluster ACL Authentication Issues
I installed the Kafka cluster using the KRAFT protocol, and during the ACL authentication, I encountered the issue 'Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator'.Below is my configuration.
server.properties
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@192.168.1.41:9093,2@192.168.1.42:9093,3@192.168.1.43:9093,4@192.168.1.44:9093
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=SASL_PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.41:9092
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
process.roles=broker,controller
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-512
authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
super.users=User:kafkaadmin
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
listener.security.protocol.map=SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT

kafka_server_jaas.conf
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="kafkaadmin"
    password="kafkaadmin123456"
    serviceName="kafka";
};

Below is the error message.
java.io.IOException: Channel could not be created for socket java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.registerChannel(Selector.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:1072)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.sendRequests(InterBrokerSendThread.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.pollOnce(InterBrokerSendThread.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.doWork(InterBrokerSendThread.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:135)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:243)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:340)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Principal could not be determined from Subject, this may be a transient failure due to Kerberos re-login
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.firstPrincipal(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:633)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.<init>(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:203)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildClientAuthenticator(SaslChannelBuilder.java:289)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.lambda$buildChannel$1(SaslChannelBuilder.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.<init>(KafkaChannel.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:237)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.registerChannel(Selector.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:1072)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.sendRequests(InterBrokerSendThread.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.pollOnce(InterBrokerSendThread.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.doWork(InterBrokerSendThread.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:135)

How can I resolve this? Thank you.
